# Use try_files with different document roots

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I know there is a suggested solution in [How to use try_files with 2 or more roots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39837080/how-to-use-try-files-with-2-or-more-roots) but it does not quite fit what I try to achieve.

We are in the process of migrating a big old webserver with 100,000s of pages to a new webserver. During this process we update the content. The directory for the new content was created from scratch. While we are updating the content we want to make sure that if something is missing in the new folder it can be retrieved from the old one.

My simplified folder structure looks like this:

```
/mnt/oldcontent
/var/opt/data/company/newcontent
```

For our scenario the ideal solution would be if we could do something like this:

```
location / {
  try_files /var/opt/data/company/newcontent/$uri /mnt/oldcontent/$uri ...;
}
```

I know this is invalid syntax.

Comment: I wonder if this could be solved with a `server` level `root` that I override with a newly defined `location` level `root` which I specify in `try_files` with something llike `@oldcontentroot`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution would need the `root` to be set to the root of the filesystem.

As a `location` can only serve a single root, you could use a named `location` to try the other one.

For example:

```
root /var/opt/data/company/newcontent;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @oldcontent;
}
location @oldcontent {
    root /mnt/oldcontent;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. And you showed me that my idea (see comment above) was not that wrong ;-)